# Automatical request decryption in Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, rest

For communication we will send encrypted messages between our app and backend. These messages contains encrypted payload which will be json. What is the best way to automatically decrypt the payload and pass it as unmarshalled object to the Spring rest controller. Should I utilize some Spring custom editors?

**UPDATE**
The problem is quite complicated as we need to use HSM and DB for decryption. I know I can handle this in filter, but I guess the approach is not really good one.
Replacing the request content seems odd to me not to mention the need for starting DB transaction.
Spring interceptors will not help as they are just alternative to filters. We thought about AOP or some Facade before each service call, which fill take care about the messege decryption and unmarshalling.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a job for spring filters. Filters can intercept your http requests. You can configure filter bean by adding component implementing `javax.servlet.Filter` interface.

```
@Component
public class EncodingFilter implements Filter {
}
```

You can read more on this matter based on example [here](https://www.taringamberini.com/en/blog/java/adding-encryption-to-a-restful-web-service/) and [here](https://pravinchavan.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/intercepting-http-request-in-spring-framework/).

Comment: But how to make it so the controller method will receive specific unmarshalled VO. The messages contains different json content that should be mapped to specific VO. Filters do not know of the type they can just decrypt. You mean after this filter the usual RequestBody unmarschalling will happen?What if only some request will be encrypted?

Comment: You will have to investigate how to configure your filter to be executed before json unmarshalling. Also, you should develop logic to determine whether request contain decoded content. I would suggest HttpHeader with an indication.

Comment: @Tomasz Bawor, I am also trying to do the same. Have you found the answer for above question.